# R: copying data from columns in one dataframe to another based on some conditions

Tags: r, copy

Here are my datasets:

df1:

**HT    AT    HHAI    HAAI   HHGC    HAGC**

AS      Ar    0.3      0.5    0.8    0.9

and so on.

I'm doing this in R.

df2:

**HT AT HHAI HAAI HHGC HAGC**

BS FS NA NA NA NA

and so on.

I want to copy values of HHAI, HAAI, HHGC, HAGC from df1 *into* same columns of df2 when:
df1.HT==df2.HT and df1.AT==df2.AT

df1 and df2 are large dataframes.

I'm very new to R. Don't know about much methods and all.

Please post the code here as I don't have much knowledge about R.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide better example and a example how you want your output to look. Also, check in merge function or different joins in dplyr package.

Comment: you can try `merge(df1, df2, by = "column_name")`

Comment: @Mislav there are two columns from both data frames which I want to compare. Basically, if value in df1.HT== df2.HT && df1.AT == df2.AT then only data should be copied from df1's column to df2's column.

Comment: than use vector of columns to merge: `merge(df1, df2, by = c("column_name", "column_name2), all.x = TRUE, all.y = FALSE)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

```
merge(df1, df2, by = c("column_name", "column_name2"), all.x = TRUE, all.y = FALSE)
```